# How to know if compiler is taking advantage of the pch.h.gch file?

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu-make, precompiled-headers

Is there a way to check to see if GCC uses the precompiled header or not?

Also, I generate `pch.h.gch` file like this:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -Wall -O3 -flto pch.h -o pch.h.gch
```

But the generated file is always named as `pch.h` and without the `.gch` extension. Why is this happening? It used to automatically add the extension. But now it doesn't.

Edit: Another question is that, is it necessary to add an include guard (e.g. #pragma once) to the precompiled header?

Comment: @KamilCuk I haven't used any guards in my `pch.h`. GCC doesn't complain. When using it, GCC gives a warning.

Comment: `Edit: Another question is that,` Please one question per question. See for example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is:

> How to know if compiler is taking advantage of the pch.h.gch file?

With the following source files:

```
==> f.hpp <==
static inline int f() { return 1; }

==> main.cpp <==
#include "f.hpp"
int main() {
    return f();
}
```

We can inspect system calls made by `gcc` to see if it opens the precompiled header:

```
$ gcc f.hpp
$ strace -e openat -ff gcc -c main.cpp 2>&1 | grep 'f\.hpp\.gch'
[pid 877340] openat(AT_FDCWD, "f.hpp.gch", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY) = 4
```

We see above that `gcc` opens, so we assume based on that that gcc uses `f.hpp.gch`.

Comment: Is this on Linux? Do these options have equivalents on Windows?

Comment: `Is this on Linux?` Yes, [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) is a linux tool. `Do these options have equivalents on Windows?` No idea, I do not work on windows. Gcc is not possible to work on windows (without some linux compatibility layer) anyway.

Comment: I use mingw64. It works well.